# Handling likes of users in DynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm pretty new to aws amplify / app sync and I couldn't find an answer for my question. 
My goal is to develop a social media database, where you can like user posts. 
The question I have is, if I should aggregate likes (with help of lambda maybe?) of posts or is there any other efficient way to get the like counts.

My schema looks like this right now

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  author: User @connection(name : "UserPost")
  message: String
  likers: [User]
  comments: [Comment] @connection(name : "PostComment")
}
```

Im thinking to add a column (like_count) which is getting incremented (by lambda maybe?) when I mutate the likers array. Is that a good way to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle this is to use [DynamoDB streams](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/).  If you had another DynamoDB table that contained the PostId as the partition Key and the UserId as the Sort Key, you can use the streams to control a like count aggregate attribute on your Post table.  Increment the value when a new like record is created and decrement the value when someone deletes / unlikes a post.